# Taking random samples from a python generator

Tags: python, python-3.x, random, python-itertools

I'm using the function `for pair in itertools.combinations(bug_map.keys(), 2):` to generate all pairs of elements in my db. The problem is that the amount of element is around 6.6 K and so the number of combinations is 21.7 M. Also, combinations are emitted in lexicographic sort order.

Supposing that I would take random pairs from the generator without "yielding" all of them (just a subset of n dimension), what can I do?

Comment: Can't you forego the generator entirely and just pick random keys from `bug_map.keys()`?

Comment: Yes but this way I'll lose the probability ranking and this would have an effect of probability estimation algorithms I'm using in the next phase.

Comment: I don't understand how picking pairs of random keys differs in "probability ranking" from trying to pick random elements from `combinations`. Perhaps you'd like to post more detail about that in your question.

Comment: How many random combinations do you want to generate? This is more relevant as it may seem, as it influences the probability of collisions and hence how to handle those.

Comment: @tobias_k As I understood from question the number of combinations generated randomly should be considerably smaller than total number of possible combinations. At least questioner would ask to replace all combinations with just random subset.

Comment: removing an element from the starting set implies removing all combination with that element. Some elements are most prone to give me a positive label so removing from the start implies to remove a huge portion of possible positive combinations. Removing elements from the combinations set let me preserve also a portion of this element and limiting a possible drawback while downscaling

Answer (score 0):

If you're allowed to get all `6K` elements as a list you first get all of them and then use standard python's `random.choices()` to generate batch of samples with replacement. Then apply sorting (as combinations are sorted). Then remove tuples that have same element inside twice or more and tuples that are equal. Repeat batch generation till we get enough `n` number of tuples.

You may specify any `k` as a length of desired tuples to generate in my code, and `n` to be the number k-length tuples to generate.

This algorithm generates similar probability distribution pattern as creating all combinations of `k` length and then choosing random subset of size `n`.

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##VVJNb5wwFLz7V0yVCzSbBJooh5W2p1a9VD31hlBk2LeLgzHINg3bP799tmlQfLDs8byPmefp4rvRPF6vaphG62GlOY6DEDfpcO@IjlmR4wbfRvhOOYxGX3AaLTw5r8wZfkQn/xAsTXY8zq1qNK15GHOz9k4IjQO0cj7jhzNlZVEUO4Qdt3h@Loo8lPi@yGHi4EDEeILUGspMswdpGsiERD0n@sLcn2TOvgsskm0HP4dAbuVMhqz0JAwTHwtm/pqHhmxgRpL7wBKN9Bx@wCCXrNzB4OEBT/mHsP5uC3SpQ8n9mZbEIC8NvbjgHOuTQ3OUWPYIAPu25FAnKPeS7qzCERYh2BWmV7UQb53ibL/tTHsBXkzXZDIm5Ph6gEloWCmG92pv6ne0sST7eJPhNc2s7UbVklutDvl0nu8QnOvxGVFxUPhjNeH/sJI2h5PlS/Td4U2xyTxZLds4gfdaq8TQ1i2qaFC2YrJSXKZn/LWOP@WVsyF10@c86YCpDUsN1bnYdFayKuokM5ApkGVV7uvNEBX/R0YFPh1AZeLxp@Ijk/@qKaNqf1fWjIRALssqo4EMxpgt11r4Xk4TmWNGuRCTVcZnqzBdqXrrmrGkgQ9RBTlu/nr9Bw)

```
import random

#random.seed(0) # Do this only for testing to have reproducible random results

l = list(range(1000, 1000 + 6600)) # Example list of all input elements

k = 2 # Length of each tuple to generate
n = 30 # Number of tuples to generate

batch = max(1, n // 4) # Number of k-tuples to sample at once
maybe_sort = lambda x: sorted(x) if is_sorted else x

res = []

while True:
    if len(res) >= n:
        res = res[:n]
        break
    a = random.choices(range(len(l)), k = k * batch) # Generate random samples from inputs with replacement
    a = sorted(res + [tuple(sorted(a[i * k + j] for j in range(k))) for i in range(batch)])
    res = [a[0]]
    for e in a[1:]:
        if all(e0 != e1 for e0, e1 in zip(e[:-1], e[1:])) and res[-1] != e:
            res.append(e)

print([tuple(l[i] for i in tup) for tup in res])
```

Comment: You're drawing with replacement when you should be drawing without replacement. You need `random.sample`.

Comment: I see you do this to not get the same combination twice (as you could by just repeatedly calling `sample` with sample size 2), but this way you can also _never_ get two combinations that share just a single element.

Comment: @tobias_k When you wrote this comment I've already realized this thing before and was half-way implementing new algorithm based on random population `with replacemenent`. Updated description and code. For me this algorithm now looks like correct.

Comment: @F.Petrulio My algorithm above is implemented in pure Python, because you told there are just `6.5K` elements which is fraction of second to process in such algorithm in pure Python. If perfomance is the issue I may easily re-implement my algorithm using `numpy`, just tell.

Comment: Also if there are some mathematical issues in my algo then we can figure out the right correction and I'll improve it.

Answer (score 0):

This may seem trivial, but if your desired number of samples is considerably smaller than the total number of possible combinations (21.8 M), then you could just repeatedly generate a `ramdom.sample` until you have sufficiently many. There may be collisions, but (again, if the required number of samples is comparatively small) the probability for those will be negligible and not cause a slow-down.

```
import random

lst = range(6000)
n = 1000000
k = 2

samples = set()
while len(samples) < n:
    samples.add(tuple(random.sample(lst, k)))
```

Even for 1,000,000 random samples, this produced only about ~12k collisions, i.e. about 1% of "wasted" iterations, which is probably not that much of a problem.

Note that other than `combinations`, the pairs returned by `ramdom.sample` are not ordered (the first element can be larger than the second), so you might want to use `tuple(sorted(...))`

Comment: You probably also need to sort elements within each tuple as combinations tuples are always sorted too.