# Excluding a set of tuples from a ranged random sample in python

Tags: python, numpy, random, sampling

I randomly sample N tuples from two different sets of numbers as follows:

```
set1 = [list(range(10))]
set2 = [list(range(10,20))]

c1 = np.random.choice(set1,N) #ex [9,3,7,8]
c2 = np.random.choice(set2,N) #ex [15,13,19,12]
tuples = np.concatenate([c1,c2],axis=1) #ex [[9,15],[9,19],[3,12]]
```

For the next iteration I want to sample c1,c2 again but excluding the unique tuples I already have. The numbers can appear again but just not the same combination of (number1,number2). Ideally that would be something like:

```
new_tuples = np.random.choice([set1,set2],exclude=tuples)
```

One could just check them with np.unique and resample but I was hopping for it to be a more efficient way.

EDIT: Getting all possible combinations beforehand will be to expensive.

Comment: how about you go with `itertools.product` and build all possible tuples beforehand, then use `randm.choice` on that ?

Comment: I've thought about that but I'm thinking if it will be to heavy as this is run in parallel and the sets can be really large. @Rabinzel

Comment: another idea was to make a little while loop where you come up with random tuples (checking if already in a set)  till your target length is reached. but I think you have similar thing with np.unique already in mind, right ?

Comment: Yea, to resample multiple times until I find the "correct combinations" might take a long time. But I might just a variant of itertools.product and hope it dosen't break @Rabinzel

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/64060720/15521392 it seems there was already something similar and after a quick look, it seems like nobody came up with a more efficient way...see yourself

Comment: The thing is if you perform a lot of iterations, the number of tuple can be close to all the combination. In such case you certainly have to memorize all the previous tries which is relatively equivalent to generating the combination initially. Note that the while solution is efficient only if the number of tuple picked so far is much smaller than the total number of possible tuples. There is no free lunch. Do you know the number of iteration ahead of time? By the way nothing prevent the same tuple to be picked twice in `tuples` in this current solution.

Answer (score 0):

After asker comment, I fixed the code:

```
import numpy as np
import time
begin = time.time()
N = 4
set1 = list(range(10**6))
set2 = list(range(10**6, 20**6))
c1 = np.random.choice(set1,N) #ex [9,3,7,8]
c2 = np.random.choice(set2,N)
tuples = set(list(zip(c1, c2)))
print(tuples)
c1 = np.random.choice(set1,N) #ex [9,3,7,8]
c2 = np.random.choice(set2,N)
new_tuples = set([(n1, n2) for (n1, n2) in list(zip(c1, c2)) if (n1, n2) not in tuples][0:4])
print(new_tuples)
print(tuples | new_tuples)
print(time.time() - begin)
```

Comments explain step by step. Tested 20 bilions, it returned in 13 seconds!
Output obtained:

```
##{(315090, 13207382), (175935, 7922219), (249258, 59598185), (45681, 27246043)}
```

{(446782, 45042493), (122963, 12794175), (388061, 20418275), (328064, 48911155)}
{(315090, 13207382), (175935, 7922219), (328064, 48911155), (446782, 45042493), (249258, 59598185), (45681, 27246043), (122963, 12794175), (388061, 20418275)}
12.917975664138794

Comment: This solution is very inefficient for large sets, especially when the number of sample if large compared to the total number of tuples. The while loop create a new growing set for each iteration. This means that to generate `n` tuples, the complexity is at least `O(n**2)`. In fact, when the number of item to generate is large, the while has to do many tries resulting certainly in a complexity close to `O(n**2 Hn) ~ O(n**2 log n)`. Additionally, set of tuples will consume a significant amount of memory when `n` is large (compared to Numpy arrays).